# Unxepcted ClassCastException from findViewById

Tags: java, android, classcastexception

I have the following code in xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id = "@+id/buttonsLayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_gravity = "center"
     app:columnCount="4"
     app:rowCount="4"
     app:useDefaultMargins="false"
     >
</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

and I'm filling this GridLayout dynamicly so I'm trying to get the object with:

```
android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout gl = 
    (android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonsLayout);
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintButton cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout at com.education4all.mathcoach.TaskActivity.onCreate(TaskActivity.java:134)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2033)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2104) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:132) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1157) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556) 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is very strange because this code used to work and suddenly this error appears. Why could that be?

build_gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.education4all.mathcoach"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionName '1.0.2'
        versionCode 4
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.+'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried invalidate and restart?

Comment: Sounds like your IDs got screwed up.  Try a clean and then rebuild.

Comment: @SwapnilMeshram None of that helped

Comment: @GaryBak didn't help sadly.

Comment: Could you provide us with your build.gradle and activity's layout xml files?

Comment: @Seishin added both

Comment: @UpmostScarab could you add the app's build.gradle file not the project's one? :)

Comment: @UpmostScarab try to use a higher version of the support library, i.e.: ```com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+```, clean and try to run the project.

Comment: @Seishin That worked, thanks! Should I also use newer version of GridLayout? Also could you create and answer? Or I will close the question.

Comment: You shouldn't generally mix the versions of app compat libraries.  I'm surprised it would cause this issue, but it could cause other issues (like NoSuchMethodException or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use a higher version of the support library, i.e.: `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.+`, clean and try to run the project.

You can also use the latest version of the GridLayout as well.